# "Is that ok?" formal letter

Tags: phrase-usage, formal-language, email, correspondence

I'm writing a formal e-mail, asking about something I will do (submit a partial academic record). I want to ask if that's ok or if there is any problem about that, but formally.

Is it possible to use "if that's ok or if there is any problem about that"? Or is there any alternate phrase to use?

Comment: Why not just say something like "Would it be all right..." instead of "Would it be OK..."? It's always safer to use something which you know is correct rather than something you are not quite so sure about.

Comment: t's not 'ok', especially since the word you are talking about is either "okay" or "OK".

Answer (score 1):

"Is that ok"? Probably not.

You might want to ask

> May I submit a partial academic record?

Answer (score 1):

No, do not use "ok" in any formal letter. You can use it on an email, to a friend or relative, however if you are writing a formal letter, you need to avoid using slogans, etc.